# Effective way of Parsing JSON Data into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, ejs

I am building a website for recording and viewing patients data. In server side, I am using Node.js+express and I am rendering the pages with ejs. I am able to transfer to data within the pages without issues. However,I am stuck with parsing the JSON data. In my code:

```
 // Get all patients in the system
    app.get('/patients', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log("ALL PATIENTS PAGE");
        getRequestCounter++;
        console.log("Processed Request Counter --> GET: " +  getRequestCounter + ", POST: " + postRequestCounter + ", PUT: " + putRequestCounter +", DELETE: " +deleteRequestCounter);
        Patient.find({},function(err, data){
            console.log("DATA IS HERE" + data);
            if(err) throw err;
            res.render("patients", {collection: data});
        });

        console.log('received GET request.');
    })
```

I am getting all the patients info from MongoDb and pass it to the patients.ejs page as raw data.

```
 <div class="middle">

  <h2> Patients Information</h2>
  <p> <%= collection%></p>

</div>
```

When I pass it the output is seem as follows: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrvFY.png)

So, I would like to know an effective and nice way to parse the JSON data which will look beautiful in HTML. Thanks a lot!

Comment: that should do the work  $scope.patients = JSON.parse(data recieved);

Comment: It didn't work.